# No such file or directory when trying to upload images in Django

Tags: python, django

I have an ImageField on a Profile model so users can upload images. However, when I try to upload an image I get this error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\Projects\\project\\media\\image.png'`. When I look in the database, the profile_image field gets popuated as "image.png" but the file doesn't appear in any folders in the project.

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
def validate_image(image):
    file_size = image.file.size
    limit_kb = 1000
    if file_size > limit_kb * 1024:
        raise ValidationError("Max size of file is %s KB" % limit_kb)

class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images/', blank=True, null=True, validators=[validate_image])
```

views.py

```
 profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
            updatedProfile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            updatedProfile.save()
            currentuser.email = request.POST['email']
            currentuser.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Profile successfully updated!')
            return redirect('viewprofile', slug=profile)
```

forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['profile_image', ...]
```

template

```
<label for="profile_image">Profile Image (size cannot exceed 1 MB)</label></p>
                          <input id="profile_image" type="file" class="" name="profile_image">
```

Comment: Have you included `enctype='multipart/form-data`?

Comment: no, where does that go? In the input form? I'll give it a try

Comment: Yes, you need to include this when you are using forms that have a file upload control, otherwise it will not work

Comment: yup that was it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='action-url' >`